# How to control defaultValue of React Native's <TextInput>?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, textinput, jsx

I have a `<TextInput/>` with a `defaultValue` set up and a button where it would trigger and pass the `defaultValue` of `<TextInput>` elsewhere.

But how do I pass in the `<TextInput/>`'s `defaultValue` to the `onPress` method of `<TouchableHighlight/>`?

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
changeName(text) {
    this.setState({nameNow: text}) //How can I immediately set the defaultValue='PassMeIn' to nameNow? Because this method would never be called unless text is changed within TextInput
}

sendOff() {
    //Would like to access the defaultValue='PassMeIn' here whenever sendOff() is called. How can I?
}

render() {

    return (
      <View>
            <TextInput 
                defaultValue='PassMeIn' 
                onChange={this.changeName} 
                value={this.state.nameNow}
            />
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.sendOff}/>
                <Text>Button</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For one, the `render` method can't return multiple nodes. I believe the `<TextInput/>` should be wrapped by the `<TouchableHighlight/>` component, like:

```
render() {

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.sendOff}>
      <TextInput 
        defaultValue='PassMeIn' 
        onChange={this.changeName} 
        value={this.state.nameNow}
      />
    </TouchableHighlight>    
  )
}
```

This will make it possible to pass a prop through from `<TouchableHightlight>` to `<TextInput` to use as the `defaultValue` and you'll have access to it in the `<TouchableHighlight>` component.

Comment: I made the changes to the code in the original post. Please take a look.

Comment: I faced the issue setting integer value as default. value.toString() solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can store the defaultValue inside a new state and then you can access it in both places

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  //...other state
  defaultValue: "PassMeIn"
 };

//...other code

sendOff() {
  //...do things with this.state.defaultValue
}

render() {

  return (
    <TextInput 
        defaultValue={this.state.defaultValue} 
        onChange={this.changeName} 
        value={this.state.nameNow}
    />
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.sendOff}/>
)
}
```

Comment: I faced the issue setting integer value as default. value.toString() solved my problem.